# Php issue uploading file zip

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, reset

I'm having trouble with an application in creating, the user submits a file then it gets analized.

The issue I have is that I can't get the file to upload properly, when it reaches the 100% upload (notified in chrome status bar) it starts again then when the page loads, tells me no file was received!!

here is my code:

```
 #upload form //just a basic form

 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="test_lib_valida.php"  

enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" class="info">OPERACIÓN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><label for="oper2"></label>
      <select name="oper2" id="oper2">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">Altas</option>
        <option value="2">Bajas</option>
        <option value="3">Cambios</option>
      </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><label for="archivo2">Seleccione archivo</label>
      <input type="file"  name="archivo2" id="archivo2" multiple /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And on the php side // just gets the file and shows where it's stored for now

```
$tam_allow=7454720000;//max filezise
$tipos=array("application/octet-stream","application/x-zip-compressed","text/plain");//allowed types
$ext=array("zip","txt");//allowed exts
$what=getArchivo("archivo","elarchivonuevo","recibidos/",$tam_allow,$ext,$tipos);
echo "El archivo queda en:".$what[1];
showinfo("archivo");
```

And the getArchivo function //gets the file and sends it to the appropiate folder, returns the final URL to find the file, if its zipped it decompresses it and saves the txt inside, then eliminates the zip

```
    function getArchivo($nombre,$nuevo_nom,$ruta,$maxsizeb=204800000000000,$allowedExts = array("txt"),$tipos)//verifica un archivo subido y lo mueve a la carpeta especificada, la ruta va con diagonal recibidos/, si tiene exito regresa [0]1 y [1]ruta archivo
{
//verifica el nombre del folder, 1 para cada dependencia, la cve de la dependencia esta en la variable de sesion "id_dep"
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["$nombre"]["name"]));
//variable de sesion para obtener la extension fuera de aqui
      if(!$nuevo_nom)
      $nuevo_nom=$nombre;
      if($tipos)
      $tip= in_array($_FILES["$nombre"]["type"],$tipos);
      else
      $tip=1;
if (
    $tip
    && 
    ($_FILES["$nombre"]["size"] < $maxsizeb)
    && 
    in_array($extension, $allowedExts)
   )
  {
  if ($_FILES["$nombre"]["error"] > 0)//error de subida
    {
      if($_FILES["$nombre"]["error"]==UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL)//no subio completo
        {
            mensaje("Archivo Recibido Parcialmente, intentelo de nuevo");
            //redirige("index_2.php");
        }
        else
    mensaje("Error de subida: " . $_FILES["$nombre"]["error"]);
    //redirige("index_2.php");
    $result[0]=0;
    }
  else
    {
  //showinfo("archivo");
  //ya paso, va pa su carpeta
      try
      {
              //echo ("$ruta" . $nuevo_nom.'.'.$extension);
          if($extension=='zip')//viene comprimido
          {
          //mensaje("archivo Comprimido detectado");
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["$nombre"]["tmp_name"],$ruta.$_FILES["$nombre"]["name"]);
          //mensaje("moviendo:".$_FILES["$nombre"]["tmp_name"]." como ".$ruta.$_FILES["$nombre"]["name"]);
          descomprime($ruta.$_FILES["$nombre"]["name"],$ruta);
          //mensaje("descomprimiendo:".$ruta.$_FILES["$nombre"]["name"]." en ".$ruta);
          //cambiamos nombre al archivo
          rename(str_replace('zip','txt',$ruta.$_FILES["$nombre"]["name"]),$ruta.$nuevo_nom.'.txt');
          //como se llamo
          $_SESSION["recibido"]=$_FILES[$nombre]["name"];
          $_SESSION["formato"]=$extension;
          $_SESSION["tamano"]=$_FILES[$nombre]["size"];
          //quitamos el zip
          unlink($ruta.$_FILES["$nombre"]["name"]);
          $result[0]=1;
          $result[1]=$ruta . $nuevo_nom.'.txt';
          }
          else//es txt
          {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["$nombre"]["tmp_name"],$ruta.$nuevo_nom.'.txt');  
          $_SESSION["recibido"]=$_FILES[$nombre]["name"];
          $_SESSION["formato"]=$extension;
          $_SESSION["tamano"]=$_FILES[$nombre]["size"];
          $result[0]=1;
          $result[1]=$ruta . $nuevo_nom.'.txt';
          }
      }
          catch (Exception $e)
          {    
         mensaje($e->getMessage());
         }
    }
  }
else
  {
  mensaje("ARCHIVO NO PERMITIDO, POR EL MOMENTO SOLO SE ACEPTAN ARCHIVOS EXTENSION (ZIP,TXT)");
  //redirige("index_2.php");
  $result[0]=0;
  $result[1]="";
  //info del archivo
  //showinfo("archivo");
  }
  return $result;
}
```

And the descomprime code //just decopresses if the file contains a txt file inside with the same name as the zip

```
function descomprime($nomarch,$ruta)//takes the file and decompresses it if its a zip file
 {
try
{
     $zip = new ZipArchive;
     $res = $zip->open($nomarch);
     $nombrebusca=str_replace("zip","txt",$nomarch);
     $nombrebusca= basename($nombrebusca);
    $esta= $zip->locateName($nombrebusca);
    if($esta===0)//verifica que lo de adentro se llame como lo de afuera
    {
     if ($res === TRUE) {
         $zip->extractTo($ruta);
         $zip->close();
              mensaje("Archivo descomprimido correctamente:".$esta);
         //echo 'ok';
     } else {
         mensaje ('Problema al descomprimir el Archivo, Por favor verifique que se pueda descomprimir');
         //redirige("index_2.php");
     }
        }
    else
    {
     mensaje ('El archivo comprimido no contiene el archivo de texto requerido');
     //redirige("index_2.php");
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
 }
```

The mensaje function just sends an alert via javascript

The weird thing is that on my laptop install, it works like a charm, but on the server install it shows the error, the thing is, all php and apache conf is the same on both installations, now im wondering whats going on!!

I get the errors even from files as small as 3 mb, all lower ones are passing thru.

Sometimes I get `Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE):` or a response from my application that says that the file isn't valid.

on php i have

```
memory limit=512
upload_max_filesize 100M
post_max_size 100M
max_input_time 300
max_execution_time 300
//And all the folders have 777 permission
```

is there somtehing I'm missing?

Comment: Just wanted to add that "analize" is funny. Thank you.

Comment: If it works on your laptop but not on the server, what's the difference between the first one and the second one ? Don't you try to upload a `.extension` file on the first one and a `.EXTENSION` file on the second that wouldn't match the `in_array` on $allowedExts ?

Comment: Take a look on the permissions of your server's upload directory.

Comment: @RelevantUsername: yes on both i tried to upload the .zip and .txt files and the big ones get rejected

Comment: @Luigi Siri the directories im using have 777 permissions, thats why im confused, could it be something on the network? i mean on my laptop it doesnt have to travel anywhere, and on the server there are several points where the files could be blocked, could that be a possibility?

Comment: Do some debugging. In test_lib_valida.php, just output the $_FILES variable. print_r($_FILES)

Comment: it seems to be a network problem, solved no, thanks!! (i dont know what the guys at infrastructure did, sorry :S)